# How can I pass the screen resolution to my shader in pyOpengl

Tags: python, shader, pyopengl

Started to learn how to work with shaders. But I can't solve one problem. Help, please.
I need to tell the shader the resolution of my screen.  Maybe I'm using the wrong parameters?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *


def create_shader(shader_type, source):
    shader = glCreateShader(shader_type)
    glShaderSource(shader, source)
    glCompileShader(shader)
    return shader


pygame.init()
display = (1000, 800)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)

fragment = create_shader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, """
    #version 330
    uniform vec2 iResolution;
    void main()
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(gl_FragCoord.x / iResolution.x, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0); 
    }
""")

program = glCreateProgram()
glAttachShader(program, fragment)
glLinkProgram(program)
glUseProgram(program)

k = glGetAttribLocation(program, 'iResolution')
print(k)
glVertexAttrib2d(0, display[0], display[1])

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glPointSize(1000)
    glBegin(GL_POINTS)
    glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0)
    glVertex2f(0.5, 0.0)
    glEnd()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

The current code snippet does not work.
k always equals -1...

Answer (score 0):

`iResolution` is not an attribute, but a uniform. Get the location with [`glGetUniformLocation`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetUniformLocation.xhtml) and set the value with [`glUniform2f`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml):

```py
glUseProgram(program)
k = glGetUniformLocation(program, 'iResolution')
glUniform2f(k, display[0], display[1])
```

Comment: @YevgenyAntonov Of course it works. The problem is that you have no vertex shader. You need a vertex and fragment shader.

Comment: Sorry. thank you very much. everything is working now.